# How to maintain scrollview position upon exiting and re-entering tab in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, tabbar

I have a simple iPhone tabbar app, both have scrollviews. When I switch between the two tabs, the scrollview position is reset back to its top position. How can I maintain the scrollview position, upon switching tabs and comging back, so that the scrollview will be in the exact position that I left it in?

I've tried different things with `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear`, but to no avail. Seems I'm missing something simple. This is obviously not complex. Thanks!!

Comment: It's not supposed to be complex - I can't reproduce your issue in a fresh tab bar application project. There must be some interaction with something else you're doing.

Comment: Well there are 2 tabs. The first one has multiple rectangular views, and each view has a webview inside of it.  The second tab has multiple buttons.  And of course, each tab has a scrollview over the whole view area.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state in a variable and while coming back you can just initialise with that value.

If you want that the same state is maintained even after launching the app, save the state in plist, userdefaults.

Comment: Sorry if I'm nesting questions here, but how do I "save the state in a variable and while coming back you can just initialise with that value"??  I'm sorta new to iOS dev... thanks for your understanding in advance.